# how to exit command line automatically after yeoman command run and how to stop displaying output of command in cmd

Tags: cmd, command, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

hi i am working with yeoman package 
i need to automate few thing 
this is the my code 
i have two batch files

file one

```
echo *****npm install -g generator-%1*****
start /wait  mybatch.bat %1
echo *****creata app folder*****
mkdir cmdtestnew
cd cmdtestnew
echo *****run new app*****
yo %1
cd ..
```

file two

```
@echo OFF
npm install -g generator-%1
exit
```

i am calling this batch file using bellow command in command prompt

```
   > fileone anugular
```

problem 1 : how can i exit that popup command prompt automatically and complete process in first command prompt

problem 2: how can i stop displaying output of that command in pop-up command line (file two )

Comment: most command like npm should have a silent or quiet switch, which should solve your first problem.   Like /S  or /q or -q or /quiet

Answer (score 0):

NPM has a command line switch to turn off logging:

◾-s or –silent to turn off console logging

i.e. npm install -g generator-%1 -silent

Comment: Have you tried the npm install -g generator-%1 -s on it's own?

Comment: what about "npm install -s -g generator-%1"